# Insert a Date into oracle database

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I need to insert date into my database, i have a table that contains a row date of type Date but i need to insert the date without using preparedStatement but it wont work. here is my code:

```
try{

        dbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(DR_URL, DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD);
        stmt = dbConnection.createStatement();

        for(int i=1; i<3; i++){
                        String invoiceNumber = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Invoice Number:");
                        String customerName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Customer Name:");
                        Date invoiceDate = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
                        java.sql.Date invDate = new java.sql.Date (invoiceDate.getTime());

                        stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO INVOICEMAIN VALUES ('" + invoiceNumber + "','" + customerName + "','" + setDate(invDate) + "')");
                    }

        stmt.close();
        dbConnection.close();
    }
```

Comment: `... but it wont work` What exactly doesn't work?

Comment: you should format the date, a see what is the format nls oracle configuration

Comment: Why can't you use a prepared statement, which would be the _correct_ way to do this?

Comment: you could execute ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT='DD/MM/YYYY'; before executing the insert sentence, but your invoice date should have the same format

Comment: inserting the date won't work @defaultlocale

Comment: when i printed the date the format was yy-mm-dd @OscarDavid

Comment: @MickMnemonic yes i know prepared statement would be better but i am trying without using it to insert the date and see if it works

Comment: It will work if you format the date string carefully according to the NLS settings of the session/connection -- but this approach is very fragile and error-prone. You should _always_ use parameterized SQL (prepared statements) with input variables because it's efficient, safe and easy to use.

Comment: @MickMnemonic yes you are right i think i am wasting my time on trying to insert the date without using prepared statements and the thing is i found lots of results on how to insert date using prepared statements any way thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to do this:

- Don't keep database connection live while waiting for user input. Gather the input first, *then* connect to database.
  *Reason:* If user is slow, connection may time out.
- Use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) to clean up the JDBC resources.
  *Reason:* Guaranteed cleanup, better error handling, cleaner code.
- Use [`PreparedStatement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html). Never use string concatenation with user-supplied text to build a SQL statement, because that leaves your code vulnerable to crashes, but more importantly, vulnerable to [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks, **allowing hackers to steal your data and delete your tables**.

Since you need to collect multiple sets of values, create a class for retaining those.

```java
public class Invoice {
    private final String invoiceNumber;
    private final String customerName;
    private final Date invoiceDate;
    public Invoice(String invoiceNumber, String customerName, Date invoiceDate) {
        this.invoiceNumber = invoiceNumber;
        this.customerName = customerName;
        this.invoiceDate = invoiceDate;
    }
    public String getInvoiceNumber() {
        return this.invoiceNumber;
    }
    public String getCustomerName() {
        return this.customerName;
    }
    public Date getInvoiceDate() {
        return this.invoiceDate;
    }
}
```

```java
// Prompt user for two invoices
List<Invoice> invoices = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 1; i < 3; i++) {
    String invoiceNumber = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Invoice Number:");
    String customerName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Customer Name:");
    invoices.add(new Invoice(invoiceNumber, customerName, new Date()));
}

// Insert invoices
try (Connection dbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(DR_URL, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD)) {
    String sql = "INSERT INTO INVOICEMAIN VALUES (?,?,?)";
    try (PreparedStatement stmt = dbConnection.prepareStatement(sql)) {
        for (Invoice invoice : invoices) {
            stmt.setString(1, invoice.getInvoiceNumber());
            stmt.setString(2, invoice.getCustomerName());
            stmt.setDate  (3, new java.sql.Date(invoice.getInvoiceDate().getTime()));
            stmt.addBatch();
        }
        stmt.executeBatch();
    }
}
```

Comment: It's better to us `setTimestamp()` because an Oracle `DATE` is actual that: a timestamp. `setDate()` (or more precisely `java.sql.Date`) will set the time part to `00:00:00`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name True, though an invoice date is likely supposed to be date-only without time-of-day, so using the new Java 8 `LocalDate` in the `Invoice` class would be better, and then it'd become `stmt.setDate(3, java.sql.Date.valueOf(invoice.getInvoiceDate()));`

Answer (score 0):

If you're just inserting the current date, you can use Oracle's SYSDATE function:

```
stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO INVOICEMAIN VALUES ('" + invoiceNumber + "','" + customerName + "',SYSDATE)");
```

Using the SYSDATE function will also prevent date related issues dependent on where the code executes (client machine vs a middle tier, or DB tier server).

However, I agree with @Andreas you should avoid string concatenation of user entered values when building your SQL statements.  That is unless of course you like playing fast and loose with [little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/).